# Spring Boot server port serves on 8080 even after change

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have changed the value of server.port to 8081 in one of my projects strangely it sticks to 8080 every time I run it. I tried to rebuild the project but still refuses to run on any other port than 8080.

I have other projects with ports configured to 8082 and 8083 which work just fine. I'm suscpect this to be a cache issue not being cleared as I had first run the project on 8080 after which I changed set server.port to 8081

Start Up Log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-20 19:24:24.253  INFO 4148 --- [           main] i.j.m.MovieCatalogServiceApplication     : Starting MovieCatalogServiceApplication on mobiuso-3.local with PID 4148 (/Users/pavitardua/projects/microservices/movie-catalog-service/target/classes started by pavitardua in /Users/pavitardua/projects/microservices/movie-catalog-service)
2019-04-20 19:24:24.256  INFO 4148 --- [           main] i.j.m.MovieCatalogServiceApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-20 19:24:25.428  INFO 4148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-20 19:24:25.463  INFO 4148 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-20 19:24:25.463  INFO 4148 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-04-20 19:24:25.558  INFO 4148 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-20 19:24:25.559  INFO 4148 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1259 ms
2019-04-20 19:24:25.797  INFO 4148 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-20 19:24:25.990  INFO 4148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-20 19:24:25.995  INFO 4148 --- [           main] i.j.m.MovieCatalogServiceApplication     : Started MovieCatalogServiceApplication in 7.243 seconds (JVM running for 7.755)
```

Comment: Can you upload a copy of startup log after the server has been started?

Comment: @k9yosh Check edit

Comment: Can you share the application.properties file? Also, this is while you run it on your IDE or using the .jar after assembling?

Comment: I'm usgin intellij idea and my application.properties has only one line i.e. server.port=8081

Answer (score 0):

This will probably save sometime for IntelliJ noobs like me. 
Go to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

This did the trick for me.